# jQuery selection help

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

```
    jQuery.subscribe('setIdComFamOnEditForm', function(event,ui) {
        var idButton = ui.id;
        var idComFam = jQuery("#" + idButton).name.split("-")[1];
        $("#formFamigliare").attr('action', 'detraz_update');
        $("#IdComFam").val(idComFam);
    });
```

The above code does not find the jQuery("#" + idButton).

Where Am I wrong?

Comment: any error fired? Are you using firebug?

Comment: Does it exist? How you know it does not find it? What is `subscribe`?

Comment: Try to assign it to a variable like `var selector = "#"+ui.id;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with subscribe but are you sure that ui.id is returning a value? Furthermore I don't think a jquery wrapped set  has a name property. So I don't think jQuery("#" + idButton).name will work. If you want the name attribute you would need to use the attr() method.